# how to show loading only for one item in flatlist?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, render, react-native-flatlist

i'm getting a list of products and i show it in a **flatlist**. when somebody wants to **add quantity of an item or remove an item** i will show **a loading only on that specific card**.
i shouldn't add property to list object models.

```
const Counter = ({ quantity, itemId }) => {
    console.log(quantity);
    console.log('ITEM ID ',itemId);
    return (
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Icon style={{fontSize: 25, color: '#059b9a',marginRight:25}} name='md-trash' onPress={()=> removeItem(itemId)} />
            <Icon style={{fontSize: 25, color: '#059b9a',marginRight:10}} name='md-remove'/>
            <View style={{marginRight:10, alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
                <CustomText value={`${numTranslate(quantity)}`} style={{color:'#059b9a', fontSize:22, fontWeight:'bold'}}/>
                <CustomText style={{fontSize:10}} value={'حداکثر'} />
            </View>
            <Icon style={{fontSize: 25, color: '#059b9a', marginRight:10}} name='md-add' />
        </View>
    );
}
```

i only want to show loading instead of last icon until fetch response comes.

Comment: i used redux and stored the list there. and put the component in other file and made the request there and used a state to show or hide the loading

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of `prop` that shows rather or not your data has fetched yet. Since you did not attach your data fetch, i will just assume, that you can add it to your component.

```
const Counter = ({ quantity, itemId, isLoading }) => {
    console.log(quantity);
    console.log('ITEM ID ',itemId);

    //declare conditional constant for icon
    const icon = isLoading ? <div><p>Loading...</p></div> : <Icon style={{fontSize: 25, color: '#059b9a', marginRight:10}} name='md-add' />
    return (
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Icon style={{fontSize: 25, color: '#059b9a',marginRight:25}} name='md-trash' onPress={()=> removeItem(itemId)} />
            <Icon style={{fontSize: 25, color: '#059b9a',marginRight:10}} name='md-remove'/>
            <View style={{marginRight:10, alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
                <CustomText value={`${numTranslate(quantity)}`} style={{color:'#059b9a', fontSize:22, fontWeight:'bold'}}/>
                <CustomText style={{fontSize:10}} value={'حداکثر'} />
            </View>
     {/* render conditional expression instead of jsx element */}
     {icon}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: it's gonna apear on every single item instead of only one item

Answer (score 0):

your main component where using Counter :

```
   // Call setState here or anywhere you want to fetch data or...
   fetchData =()=> {
        this.setState({isLoading: true});
        axios.post(url).then(response=>{
          this.setState({isLoading: false});
       })
   }

   render(){
     return(
       <Counter quantity={quantity} itemId={itemId} isLoading={this.state.isLoading} />
     )
   }
```

your Counter object:

```
const Counter = ({ quantity, itemId, isLoading }) => {
    console.log(quantity);
    console.log('ITEM ID ',itemId);
    return (
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Icon style={{fontSize: 25, color: '#059b9a',marginRight:25}} name='md-trash' onPress={()=> removeItem(itemId)} />
            <Icon style={{fontSize: 25, color: '#059b9a',marginRight:10}} name='md-remove'/>
            <View style={{marginRight:10, alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
                <CustomText value={`${numTranslate(quantity)}`} style={{color:'#059b9a', fontSize:22, fontWeight:'bold'}}/>
                <CustomText style={{fontSize:10}} value={'حداکثر'} />
            </View>
            {isLoading ?
            <LoadingIcon />
            :
            <Icon style={{fontSize: 25, color: '#059b9a', marginRight:10}} name='md-add' />
            }
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Will it cause every item to load rather than the particular item. Cause you're passing this.state.isLoading to every item in the flatlist.

Comment: change <Counter quantity={quantity} itemId={itemId} isLoading={this.state.isLoading && islastItem} /> just send true in your last item

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi what if user wants to press two items in a row? it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you want that users click just one item then you can send isDisabled state to the other items or if you want loading in per item clicked then you have to save items ID and send to them isLoading in your loop where you create all Counter's

Answer (score 0):

1) Maintain an array in the state like **loadingItems**. In the onPress, push the **itemId** into **loadingItems** before the try block. whether if the call succeed or not, pop the **itemId** that is within the try or catch block.

2) Add a loading prop to your component and check if the **itemId** is in the **loadingItems** array.

```
<Card 
isLoading={this.state.loadingItems.includes(item.Id)
...
/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there any library or something to do what i want? i've seen a lot of apps having this feature. how do they do that?

Comment: You won't need a library. Try to implement my solution it will work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new variable **loadingItem**.
2. Store the itemId in **loadingItem** before you call your **fetchData** method
3. Check if **loading** is true and **itemId** equals **loadingItem**

   ```
    {loading && itemId === loadingItem ? <LoadingIcon />
        :
        <Icon style={{fontSize: 25, color: '#059b9a', marginRight:10}} name='md-add' />
        }
   ```